# Sort month and year in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to sort the month-year data in r, I tried using this

```
Data_Full$Year_Month <- paste(Data_Full$Year, Data_Full$Month, sep = "")
for(i in 1: length(Data_Full$Year_Month)){

  if(length(Data_Full$Year_Monthi[i] == 5)){
    Data_Full$Year_Month[i] <- paste(substr(Data_Full$Year_Month[i], 1, 4), "0", substr(Data_Full$Year_Month[i], 5, nchar(Data_Full$Year_Month[i])), sep = "")

  } else

  {
    Data_Full$Year_Month[i] <- Data_Full$Year_Month[i] 

  }
  i

}
```

Once I get this I will sort it, but I unable to do it

Comment: What format is your month data in? IE (January, Jan, 1, 01, ...etc)

Comment: Year Month
2014 6
2014 6
2014 6
2014 6
2014 6
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7
2014 7

Comment: Please update your question rather than replying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you back a new date column, which you can then sort normally.

```
# Test dataframe
Data_Full <- data.frame(Year = rep(2017,12),
                        Month = c(12:1))

# Create a date column from Month and Year
Data_Full$Date <- as.Date(apply(Data_Full, 1, function(x){
                                                paste0(x["Year"], ifelse(nchar(as.character(x["Month"])) == 2, x["Month"], paste0(0,x["Month"])), "01")
                                              }), format = "%Y%m%d")

# Order dataframe by date
Data_Full <- Data_Full[with(Data_Full, order(Date)),]
```

Comment: As a side note, if you don't actually want the data stored as a date and only want a string value in YYYYMM format, just remove the `as.Date` wrapper and it's `format = "%Y%m%d"` argument from around the `apply` function